# How to disable a option in a dropdown with radio button, all in the same dropdown. with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, radio-button

I have a page with multiple dropdown's and radio buttons selections loaded with js .

how do i disable option with radio button all in the same selection dropdown.

For example

radio button 1 will show quantity option value 1, value 2 and value 3
radio button 2 will show quantity value 4, value 5 and value 6

so I don't have to create a different quantity dropdown, I can use one quantity dropdown, and control what options the customer sees with two radio buttons.

what i can think is, it should be thru the option value, when you click radio one, it should disable and hide value number xx.

Any help is greatly appreciate.

Comment: Can you try to explain better? Maybe some code, a fiddle, a picture.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1CcIbDB

Comment: For example if you click the "the line selection i should be able to hide some options in the quantity.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `display:none;` or a hidden class to an option in your select box. In your case you can do this with javascript.

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option style="display:none;">3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Option 3 will not display in this example.

Alternatively you could just rebuild the contents of your select box in javascript.

```
function displayOptions (block) {
    var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');

    if (block === 1) {
        mySelect.innerHTML = '<option>1</option><option>2</option>';
    } else { 
        mySelect.innerHTML = '<option>3</option><option>4</option>';
    }

    //TODO you can select a new default here or it will default to the first option
}

//TODO bind a change event to your radio buttons and invoke the displayOptions function
```

Comment: Hi, it needs to be based on the dropdown selection, For example if lines is selected it should disable, and crate a class so we can hide the "quantity 100 option"

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet as I am unsure what you mean by "based on the dropdown selection"

Comment: "clickerWrapper":function(fieldMeta, $func){return (!$("#"+fieldMeta.baseID).length ) ? false : $("#"+fieldMeta.baseID).bind("click",$func);},
 "executable":function(fieldMeta,$func) {
 
  var passonArgs = [].splice.call(arguments,0);
  passonArgs.splice(0,2);
  passonArgs.unshift(fieldMeta);
  $func.apply(this, passonArgs);
 },
 "refrashSwatches":(function(){
  var mAlert = false;
  return function(fieldMeta, disabledRadios){

Comment: $(".swatch_wrapper .attribImg").each(function(e,i){
    //remove class disabled
    $(this).removeClass("disabledSwatch");
    $(this).find("input[type=radio]").removeAttr("disabled");
   });
   
   for(var i=0; i<disabledRadios.length; i++){
    var elm = $("#"+disabledRadios[i]);
    elm.attr("disabled","disabled");
    if(elm.is(":checked")){
     if(!mAlert){
      mAlert = $("<div>",{
       'class':'appendedAlert',
       'style':'background:yellow'
      }).html("Your color selection has been reset");
      $("#attributeBox-color").append(mAlert);
     }

Comment: }
     mAlert.show().fadeOut(10000);
     $(".swatch_wrapper .attribImg:first").find("input[type=radio]").change();
    }
    elm.parent(".attribImg").addClass("disabledSwatch");
   }
  }
 }()),

Comment: This is a code sombedy made for us to maupalte the radio images,

Comment: "attrib-83-380":{"action":"refrashSwatches","actionVal":[['attrib-2-13', 'attrib-2-8']]},//                              This is a code somebody made for us to manipulate the radio button images, how do we change that, the radio button should change options in the quantity dropdown, like remove options based on the radio selection.